# UDP packet byte array size after AES encryption

Tags: java, udp, arrays, aes, encryption

So basically I've created a simple chat application between a server and a client using UDP sockets. The messages are encrypted using AES before they are sent. However, now I have a problem regarding the size of the byte array used to contain the messages sent. For now my byte arrays have a size of 16.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
```

But now I'm stuck with this byte size. If I try to send a message that exceeds 16 bytes, it gives me a BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded, and after that messages of any size that I send will give me the same error.

If I try to increase the size of the byte array, any messages I send will immediately give me a BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to send and receive messages that are larger than 16 bytes?

This is my encryption code:

```
    Cipher encryptor = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    Cipher decryptor = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    encryptor.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    byte[] IV = encryptor.getIV();

    packet.setData(IV);
    socket.send(packet);

    IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(IV);

    decryptor.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, ips);
```

My code to send a packet:

```
String message = input.next();
buffer = encryptor.doFinal(message.getBytes());
packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, clientIP, port);
System.out.println("Sent: " + message);
socket.send(packet);
```

And my code to receive a packet:

```
buffer = new byte[16];
packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
socket.receive(packet);
buffer = decryptor.doFinal(buffer);
String reply =  new String(buffer);
System.out.println("Received: "+ reply);
```

Comment: Messages whose size isn't a multiple of the block size (e.g. 128 bits) need to be padded. So a 128-bit block size means 16 bytes per block. The data must be 16, 32, 48, 64, etc. bytes long.

Comment: Can you show the modifications you made to try to use longer arrays

Comment: You have initialized the array with 16 byte. If you don't know on initialize, what size it need to have, try use a BinaryWriter instead, then when finished with array - .GetBuffer() will send the content to a bytearray

Comment: Whops, Java. Sorry. There may be some corresponding objects.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I just got an idea of adding dummy spaces to the message so that they fit larger blocks. Its working now, but I'm still wondering if theres a better way to do this

Comment: Are you getting an error on the decryption?  Are you sure the decryptor is using the same IV as the encryptor?

Comment: @DL001 That *is* the way to do it. The error message said the block needed padding, so you padded it. You could have used nulls instead of spaces, whatever your peer will recognise as padding.